# Jenkins Failed to Change Home Path

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

i would like to change the default path from Jenkins under /var/lib/jenkins to /data

I try a few things like change the path under /etc/default/jenkins the JENKINS_HOME or add a file under /etc/profile.d/jenkins.sh with the following content : export JENKINS_HOME=/data   i already copy all files under /var/lib/jenkins with cp -R /var/lib/jenkins/* /data   But everytime i become the following Error in the Jenkins GUI :

```
---- Debugging information ----
message             : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException
cause-message       : com.michelin.cio.hudson.plugins.rolestrategy.RoleBasedAuthorizationStrategy
class               : hudson.model.Hudson
required-type       : hudson.model.Hudson
converter-type      : hudson.util.RobustReflectionConverter
path                : /hudson/authorizationStrategy
line number         : 14
version             : not available
-------------------------------
```

env :

```
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu# env
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm
USER=root
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd                                                                                                                                                             =40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;4                                                                                                                                                             4:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;                                                                                                                                                             31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7                                                                                                                                                             z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.Z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=0                                                                                                                                                             1;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz                                                                                                                                                             =01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*                                                                                                                                                             .rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;3                                                                                                                                                             1:*.cab=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm                                                                                                                                                             =01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:                                                                                                                                                             *.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=0                                                                                                                                                             1;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*                                                                                                                                                             .m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;                                                                                                                                                             35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=                                                                                                                                                             01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.o                                                                                                                                                             gv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36                                                                                                                                                             :*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=0                                                                                                                                                             0;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
SUDO_USER=ubuntu
SUDO_UID=1000
USERNAME=root
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/us                                                                                                                                                             r/local/games
PWD=/home/ubuntu
LANG=de_DE.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/bin/su
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
SUDO_GID=1000
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
_=/usr/bin/env
root@ubuntu:/home/ubuntu#
```

root .profile File

```
 ~/.profile: executed by Bourne-compatible login shells.

if [ "$BASH" ]; then
  if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
  fi
fi

mesg n || true

export JENKINS_HOME=/data
```

Comment: What is the output for the "env" command using the terminal?

Comment: @BrunoLavit I have edit my post

Comment: Thanks @m-max :) So we can't see the JENKINS_HOME variable in your post. I'll post a solution.

Answer (score 0):

So your JENKINS_HOME environment variable is not correctly set.

For Ubuntu, you have to update this profile file `~/.profile` and add this line `export JENKINS_HOME=/data`.

Next, you have to logout/login to take into account this change.

If Jenkins is running with a system account, open a session with this account and launch this command: `. ~/.profile`

Comment: Thank you. Now i can see JENKINS_HOME=/data in my env as user ubuntu. But as root user i cant see JENKINS_HOME=/data in the env.  And Jenkins say me : /var/lib/jenkins unreachable.  I attach to my post

Comment: Your jenkins service is running as "root" or "ubuntu"?

Comment: As root User or is that not recommended ?

Comment: I have make the standard installation setup i see that an jenkins user exist they have no home directory under /home but his home directory are /var/lib/jenkins

Comment: Running something as root is not recommended. You should use a dedicated jenkins user. This user should have access to some folders like /var/lib/jenkins, /var/log/jenkins/... Maybe you can try to reinstall Jenkins using the Debian package. It should do everything for you.